# Sync multiple tracks in android

Tags: java, android

I invest my few days but not getting the correct answer.

I am developing an application in which 12 tracks should executes parallely and they are, but my problem is that the start time is not same.

Actually my question is about to sync my 12 tracks. All the tracks start at one time, there should not be millisecond difference between all tracks. If there any difference occurs then tracks mixing can not be done perfectly.

My code which play all the tracks on button click.

```
    mp1_track_a.start();
    mp1_track_b.start();        
    mp2_track_a.start();
    mp2_track_b.start();        
    mp3_track_a.start();
    mp3_track_b.start();
    mp4_track_a.start();
    mp4_track_b.start();
    mp5_track_a.start();
    mp5_track_b.start();
    mp6_track_a.start();
    mp6_track_b.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have a prallele work as you ask with a single processor with one core (you must consider the less power android device). Even tough you have multiple thraeds, in the reallity they will work sequencially.

Comment: dear gezdy This is an client requirement. And some time all tracks or 2 or 3 tracks are synced. It means if I can queued my tracks directly to my processor and no one interrupt in between then my tracks can be synced but till now I have no solution to control my cell phone processor. My cell phone processor is 1Ghz dual core processor and 1 GB RAM.

Comment: As I said it is impossible. By cons, you can make a sequential app controling thread executions. For example, you can execute the thread-0 from 0 millisecond to 100ms, stop it and call thread-1 to do the same thing (0-->100ms) etc.. Here the increment is 100ms, but you can refine. When you say "And some time all tracks or 2 or 3 tracks are synced", this is just a feeling. When you use your computer to listen music at the same time you print a document,  and you do your program, you think all are happening simultaneously, but not!

Comment: you can say to your client, "according to your specifications, it's impossible". To have 0 millisecond difference between 12 tracks, you should have at least a device with 1 processor with 12 cores or 2 proc with 6 cores, ...

Comment: There is already an application of IPhone "Multitracker" . This is the  you tube link where you can see  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0QWWFEmHt0 application.

Comment: It is impossible with your conception. In the iPhone app, there is surely one thread which plays the mixed music and the mixture is made before or there are some milliseconds between threads. I repeat, it is impossible to have 12 threads working synchronously without any millisecond difference with a device "1 proc - 1 core". I will stop repeating the same thing. So you understand what you understand. Good luck!